# Linux: How to send all files in the directory to remote directory via sftp

Tags: linux, sftp

Just like the title sugests I have a local dir, say:

```
/home/whoever/files_to_send
```

And I want to send all files in that dir to a remote location:

```
my_user@my.server.com:/some/remote/directory
```

How do I do that with `SFTP`?

PS. I need an answer for SFTP specificaly, I can not use SCP or anything else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `put` command with the `-r` option for a recursive copy.

```
 put [-Ppr] local-path [remote-path]
         Upload local-path and store it on the remote machine.  If the remote path name is not specified, it is given the same name it has on the local machine.  local-path may contain glob(3) char‐
         acters and may match multiple files.  If it does and remote-path is specified, then remote-path must specify a directory.

         If either the -P or -p flag is specified, then full file permissions and access times are copied too.

         If the -r flag is specified then directories will be copied recursively.  Note that sftp does not follow symbolic links when performing recursive transfers.
```

#### Interactive mode

```
$ sftp my.server.com 
Connected to my.server.com.
sftp> put -r /home/whoever/files_to_send /some/remote/directory
```

#### Single command for cron runs

```
$ cat batchfile
put -r /home/whoever/files_to_send /some/remote/directory
$ sftp -b batchfile my.server.com
```

What you should really learn from this is to read the online manual, `sftp(1)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I, preferably, need to execute it in one line command or some other clever way so I can run it via cron

Comment: @RandomWhiteTrash I added a solution so you can run it from cron.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to sync a whole dir (with all the subfolders also recursively). I could not get it done with `sftp` but I was able to do it with [yafc](http://www.yafc-ftp.com/)

Install it (OSX)

```
brew install yafc
```

Connect to the server

```
yafc sftp://user@host.com
```

Assuming "example" folder exists locally, `-r` for recursive, `-f` for forcing (no asking to overwrite)

```
put -rf example
```

In my case I need to also chmod the files because the permissions were not copied (not even with -p flag)

```
chmod 0755 example/*
```